# C# Recursive function adding

Tags: c#, recursion

TEST EXAMPLE:

b = 3

c = 19

constant = 4

Sum = 55

(3 + 7 + 11 + 15 + 19 = 55)

The logic is:Adding the numbers of an arithmetic line using recursive functioning

But my code outputs only the "return c" line

```
class Program
{
    static int Line(int b, int c, int constant, int sum)
    {

        if (b > c) return c;
        return (sum = sum + (Line(b+constant, c, constant, sum)));

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(Line(3,19,4,0));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the point is to calculate the sum then I do see why you'd pass in a `sum` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having *debugging* (just put *break points* and see what's going on), you can easily find *two errors* in your current implemtntation:

```
    static int Line(int b, int c, int constant, int sum) {
      if (b > c) 
        return sum; // return "sum", not "c"

      // "= b +" not " = sum +"
      return (sum = b + (Line(b + constant, c, constant, sum)));
    }
```

Comment: Couldn't that just be `return b + Line(b + constant, c, constant, sum);` since the assignment to `sum` is obviously not used after the `return`?

Comment: @juharr: You're right `return b + ...` is a better choice (when evident `for` loop, IMHO, is the best one); my actual goal, however, was to point out that *debugging* (*break points* on both `return`s) can help to solve the problem easily.

Comment: it does really have to `if (b > c) return sum;`. because when you are in last stack value of sum is still 0. so you can make it `if (b > c) return 0;` and no changes.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I agree, though I don't understand the point of passing in `sum` at that point. You could just add the result to whatever the "starting sum" is which the OP appears to pass in 0 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you need to pass the `sum` in at all.  In that case you can reduce it to one line if you want.  Also you might want to pick more meaningful names for the parameters.

```
static int Line(int start, int end, int increment)
{
    return start > end? 0 : start + Line(start + increment, end, increment);
}
```

So the default case is when `start > end` you just return 0.  Otherwise you add `start` to the next iteration which is adding `increment` to `start` and passing that into the recursive call.

Alternatively there is the none recursive solution

```
static int LineNonRecursive(int start, int end, int increment)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (start <= end)
    {
        sum += start;
        start += increment;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Nice implementation from *ternary operator* up to *parameters'* names, +1 from me.